# jquery layout plugin, Url with hash, IE10.0.9200.16750 -- get object doesn't support property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, layout

First time poster, long time reader.
I think a recent IE10 update (ver: 10.0.9200.16750) has caused some issue with JQuery Layout plugin when the URL has a hashtag (http://example.com#Tag).

When there is a call after the layout() call like $("#datepicker_input").datepicker() - I am getting an error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

This only happens in IE version noted.  Earlier version seems to work correctly (10.0.9200.16580).
If the Url does NOT have a hashtag on it, then no error.

This can be seen by using the noted IE Version and an example from the layout website:
http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/datepicker.html#tag
(note that the datepicker is not active and an error is thrown in the IE Dev window console)

Or a small demo file is easily created:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net/lib/js/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://layout.jquery-dev.net/lib/css/layout-default-latest.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').layout();
            $("#datepicker_input").datepicker();
            });
    </script>   
    <title>Layout, Datepicker and Url Hash Error with IE 10.0.9200.16750</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="ui-layout-north"><center><h1>North</h1></center></div>
    <div class="ui-layout-west"><center><h1>West</h1></center></div>
    <div class="ui-layout-south"><center><h1>South</h1></center></div>
    <div class="ui-layout-center">
        Date: <input id="datepicker_input" type="text" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
    </div>
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

Forgot to mention: If the layout() line is commented, then the datepicker() function is executed with no issue. Of course then the layout doesn't happen :-(.

Any suggestions on how to address?  Or am I missing something?

I need to use a hashtag in my url.
I need to have North, South, West and Center areas on the screen.
I like that in Layout plugin an area can be hide-able and that the areas can size to fit the content if needed.

I am considering different layout manager (jQuery EasyUI), but like some of the features the JQuery Layout plugin provides.

Thanks for any help/advice.
ds00424